# Roslyn compiler looking in wrong bin folder for vbc.exe

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, roslyn, system-codedom-compiler

Am really liking the new VB14 language features in VS2015 (like ?. notation and string interpolation). In our WinForms (.Net 4.5) application I use codedom compiler to run dynamic reporting code on the fly. Unfortunately this does not automatically support the new language features.

```
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler

Namespace MAF.DB.BusinessObject.ReportService
   Public Class VBReportCompiler
      Implements IReportCompiler

      Private ReadOnly ApplicationPath As String

      ''' <summary>
      ''' Create a report compiler with a reference to the location of the Wingman dlls. These need
      ''' to be referenced in the compilation, but the location differs between web and windows.
      ''' </summary>
      ''' <param name="ApplicationPath">Path to the binary folder</param>
      Public Sub New(ApplicationPath As String)
         Me.ApplicationPath = ApplicationPath
      End Sub

      Public Function Compile(convertedSourceCode As String, Optional ByRef reporter As IValidationReporter = Nothing,
                              Optional report As IBusinessObject = Nothing) As Object Implements IReportCompiler.Compile
         If reporter Is Nothing Then reporter = IOC.Dependency.Resolve(Of IValidationReporter)()
         Dim result As Object = Nothing
         Try
            If convertedSourceCode Is Nothing Then
               reporter.Add(report, "Report definition missing or blank")
            Else
               Dim params As New CompilerParameters With {
                  .GenerateExecutable = False,  ' Generate a DLL, not and EXE executable.
                  .GenerateInMemory = True,     ' Generate the assembly in memory, don't save to a file
                  .IncludeDebugInformation = True
               }

               params.TempFiles.KeepFiles = False ' don't keep temporary source files.

               ' Add a reference to necessary strong-named assemblies.
               With params.ReferencedAssemblies
                  .Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
                  .Add("System.dll")
                  .Add("System.Core.dll")
                  .Add("System.Data.dll") 'Allows use in report of ADO data types
                  .Add("System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll") 'Allows LINQ on DataTables
                  .Add("System.Drawing.dll") 'Allows access in report of GDI+ basic graphics functionality such as datatable
                  .Add("System.Xml.dll")
                  'Add References to required Wingman assemblies
                  .Add(IO.Path.Combine(ApplicationPath, "MAF.DB.dll")) 'Allows use in report of Data Access & Business Object functions and properties
                  .Add(IO.Path.Combine(ApplicationPath, "MAF.SharedClasses.dll"))
                  .Add(IO.Path.Combine(ApplicationPath, "DB.Foundation.dll"))
                  .Add(IO.Path.Combine(ApplicationPath, "MAF.Tracer.dll")) ' allows use in report of standard error messages
               End With

               ' Create the VB compiler.
               Dim provider = New VBCodeProvider() 'Use the current .Net Framework
               Dim compRes = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, convertedSourceCode)

               ' Check whether we have any compile errors.
               For Each compileError As CompilerError In compRes.Errors
                  reporter.Add(report, String.Format("Line {0}: {1}", compileError.Line, compileError.ErrorText))
               Next

               If reporter.Valid Then result = compRes.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("ReportCompiler")
            End If
         Catch ex As Exception
            reporter.Add(report, "Unknown Error: " & ex.Message)
         End Try

         If Not reporter.Valid Then Return Nothing
         Return result
      End Function
   End Class
```

In order to get it to work I've tried to add the Roslyn codedom nuget package but that generates two issues.

First problem is that it looks for the compiler in the wrong place \bin\debug\bin\roslyn\vbc.exe whereas the build process actually creates it in a folder \bin\debug\roslyn\ . Can anyone tell me how to resolve this as it fails my build server deployment?

Making a manual copy of the roslyn folder (work-around) and place it where codedom expects to find it is not a real solution but that raises the second issue that it expects an import of System.Web.HttpRequest and System.Web.HttpResponse. But am not compiling any web related code (winforms). So why is it expecting this?

Answer (score 0):

Not promising anything, but I had a similar issue which was fixed by including these lines (I'm upgrading- as existing project) in website.vbproj. They shoudl be included by nuget...

```
<Import Project="..\Solution\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\Solution\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
<Import Project="..\Solution\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\Solution\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```